# Can't update KDE plasma desktop

Tags: upgrade, kde, ppa

I have installed kubuntu-desktop on ubuntu 18.04 and tried to upgrade KDE 5.12.8 to 5.13.* or higher. But there isn't higher versions than 5.12. I tried to add repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports, but  it didn't fixed problem.

Answer (score 3):

18.04 will **not** get updated to KDE Plasma 5.13 or higher. Users of 18.04 will remain on Plasma 5.12 even with the bionic version of kubuntu-backports ppa. Currently we have 5.12.8, which is an LTS version.

If you want Plasma 5.15 (or higher), update to Kubuntu 19.04 and install the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=disco). See the release notes for Kubuntu 19.04 [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu). Or, move to KDE neon which currently has Plasma 5.16 and is based on 18.04 (but is not supported here).